# Display PHP error when submit

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an error message pop up when a user enters the current password and it's correct but enters nothing more. So e.g. User wants to change his/her password, enters current one and its correct he/she presses submit. It should display an error saying 'Please enter all fields!'. Right now it's just nothing and I'm really stuck:(

Any help would be great!

IMAGE 1: http://gyazo.com/e58f10783bf14c79de487f4eeb05f7e8

IMAGE 2: http://gyazo.com/ea789cc87166cea88453d6c1c59733b6

(here it should say, please fill out all the fields!)

My code:

```
<title>Hondac</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />



<?php
session_start();



$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

    echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2><div class="search12"><h2><a href="index.php">Home</a></h2></p></div></div>';


    if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user']))
    {
        //user is logged in

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            //start changing password
            //check fields

            $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
            $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);


            $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


            //check password against db
            include('../includes/config.php');

            $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$username'") or die ("change password failed");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
            $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

            //check passwords
            if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb && !empty($_POST['oldpassword'])) 



            {



                if (isset($_POST['repeatnewpassword']) AND isset($_POST['newpassword']) AND $_POST['newpassword'] != '') {
                    if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
                    {
                        $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$username'");
                        echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Password has been changed!</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
                    }
                    else {echo "<div class='results'>new password(s) dont match</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}

                }




            }
            else {echo "<div class='results'>current password doesnt match</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br>Try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}





            if (isset($_POST['email']) AND $_POST['email'] != '') {
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   username='$username'");
                echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Your email has been changed</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
            }}


        else
        {

            echo"
        <form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
        <label>Current Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword' required><p>
        <label>New Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
        <label>Repeat New Password:*</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
        </form>
        ";


        }}
    else
        die ("You must be logged in to change your password");


    ?>

<img src="../images/main.jpg">
```

Comment: Don't add session_start() after outputting HTML code. You'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the fields are empty:

```
if(empty($newpassword) || empty($repeatnewpassword)){
    echo 'All fields required.';
}else{
    //continue with code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a user validate class to check empty and matching for new and new confirmed. I didn't fully read your code (I assumed too much) but now I think this may work a bit better. I can't check your sql stuff but the rest should work pretty good.

```
<?php session_start();

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    class UserValidate
        {
            protected   $config;
            public  $errorCode;

            // This sets the default directory for your config file
            public  function __construct($config = '../includes/config.php')
                {
                    $this->config   =   $config;
                }

            // This gathers errors
            public  function errors($value = '',$code = 'general')
                {
                    $this->errorCode[$code] =   $value;
                }

            // This checks if your new passwords are 1) empty 2) match
            public  function CheckEqualNew($newpass1 = '',$newpass2 = '')
                {
                    // If new password is empty
                    $valid[]    =   (!empty($newpass1))? 0:1;
                    // If new password confirm is empty
                    $valid[]    =   (!empty($newpass2))? 0:1;

                    // If all is good
                    if(array_sum($valid) == 0) {
                            // Check that the new and new confirmed equal each other
                            if(md5($newpass1) == md5($newpass2))
                                $_isValid   =   1;
                            else {
                                    $_isValid   =   0;
                                    $this->errors('New Passwords Must Match','match');
                                }
                        }
                    // one of the new passwords are empty
                    else
                        // assign an error
                        $this->errors('Cannot have empty passwords','match');

                    // Return the validity
                    return (!isset($_isValid) || $_isValid == 0)? false:true;   
                }

            // This will check your database to see if username and password match
            public  function Validate($username = '',$password = '')
                {
                    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
                            include($this->config);
                            $username       =   mysql_real_escape_string($username);
                            $password       =   md5($password);
                            $sql            =   "SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password = '$password'";
                            $query          =   mysql_query($sql) or die ("change password failed");
                            $row            =   mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                        }
                    else
                        $this->errors('Username / Password Can Not Be Empty','err');

                    return ((isset($row['password']) && !empty($row['password'])) || !isset($row))? true:false;
                }

            // This will update the password
            public  function UpdatePassword($info = array())
                {
                    if(!empty($info)) {
                            include($this->config);
                            $username   =   md5($info['username']);
                            $password   =   md5($info['password']);
                            $sql        =   "UPDATE login SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username'";
                            mysql_query($sql);
                        }
                    else
                        $this->errors('Values can not be empty.','update');
                }

            // This will update the email address for the account
            public  function UpdateEmail($info = array())
                {
                    include($this->config);
                    $email      =   $info['email'];
                    $username   =   $info['username'];
                    $sql        =   "UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE username='$username'";
                    mysql_query($sql);
                }

            // This will display your errors and success
            public  function Display($err = '',$result = 'success')
                { ?>
                <div class='successmate' style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <h2><?php echo $err; ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class='successmate' style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <hr>
                    <h2><a href='<?php echo ($result == 'success')? "index.php":"changepassword.php"; ?>'><?php echo ($result == 'success')? "Thank You!":"Try again?"; ?></a></h2>
                </div>

                    <?php
                }
        } ?>
<title>Hondac</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<?php
    $_SESSION['sess_user']      =   'me';

    // Assign username from session
    if(isset($_SESSION['sess_user']))
        $username   =   $_SESSION['sess_user'];  ?>

    <div class="search1">
        <h2><?php echo $username; ?></h2>
        <div class="search12">
            <h2><a href="index.php">Home</a></h2></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    // If the session is set, continue
    if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])) {

            // Create instance of your user app
            $vEngine    =   new UserValidate();

            // If user submits change, validate
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    // This only checks the validity of your new passwords
                    // If empty or equal
                    $valiate_new        =   $vEngine->CheckEqualNew($_POST['newpassword'],$_POST['repeatnewpassword']);

                    if($valiate_new == true)
                        // This will check db if old password is valid
                        $valiate_old        =   $vEngine->Validate($username,$_POST['oldpassword']);
                }

            // If you want to see raw errors uncomment
        //  print_r($vEngine->errorCode);

            // If both new and old passwords are set
            // I would block here if one of these comes back as false
            // but that is up to you
            if(isset($valiate_new) && isset($valiate_old)) {
                    // Valid Old
                    if ($valiate_old == true) {
                            // Valid new
                            if ($valiate_new == true) {
                                    // Successful update
                                    $vEngine->UpdatePassword(array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$_POST['newpassword']));
                                    // Display success message
                                    $vEngine->Display("You have successfully changed your password.");
                                }
                            else 
                                // Display failure message -> a match error
                                $vEngine->Display($vEngine->errorCode['match'],'err');
                        }
                    else
                        // Display failure message -> a match error
                        $vEngine->Display($vEngine->errorCode['match'],'err');

                    // filter_var for email validation
                    if (isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            // Update
                            $vEngine->UpdateEmail(array("email"=>$_POST['email'],"username"=>$username));
                            // Display success message
                            $vEngine->Display("You have successfully changed your email.");
                        }
                }
            else { ?>

            <form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
                <label>Current Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword' required><p>
                <?php if(isset($vEngine->errorCode['invalid'])) echo $vEngine->errorCode['invalid']; ?>
                <label>New Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
                <label>Repeat New Password:*</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
                <?php if(isset($vEngine->errorCode['match'])) echo $vEngine->errorCode['match']; ?>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
            </form>
            <?php
                }
        }
    else
        die ("You must be logged in to change your password"); ?>

<img src="../images/main.jpg">
```

Comment: Again, same thing :( Sigh

Comment: Yes, I have used classes in HTML/CSS not in PHP besides giving them a name in 'echo'

Comment: Sorry, you know what, I see what you are trying to do, and I could make this more efficient but it would take a bit of a rewrite. I assumed that you had already validated the user by this point...but I see you are doing it all in one go. If EternalHour's solution doesn't work let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start your session before any HTML output. You need to find out if the password fields contain any data or not, only then will you process them. You also need to make sure your queries are completing as expected, if not throw an error. I added some error reporting and hopefully this will work for you.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<title>Hondac</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
    echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2><div class="search12"><h2><a href="index.php">Home</a></h2></p></div></div>';
} else {
    echo "session not started!";
}

if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])) {
        //user is logged in

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            //start changing password
            //check fields

            if (!empty($_POST['oldpassword'])) {
            $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
            } else {
                echo "Please enter your current password.";
                exit;
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['newpassword'])) {
            $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
            } else {
                echo "Please enter a new password.";
                exit;
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['oldpassword'] && $_POST['newpassword'] && $_POST['repeatnewpassword'])) {
            $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);
            } else {
                echo "Please confirm new password.";
                exit;
            }

            //check password against db
            include('../includes/config.php');

            $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `login` WHERE `username`='$username'");
            if (!$queryget) {
                die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget);
            if ($numrows != 1) {
                echo "<div class='results'>Password change failed.</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";
            } else {
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
                $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];
            }

            //check passwords
            if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb) {

                if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword) {
                    $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE `login` SET `password`='$newpassword' WHERE `username`='$username'");
                    if (!$querychange) {
                        die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Password has been changed!</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='results'>new password(s) don't match</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";
                }

            } else {
                echo "<div class='results'>Current password doesn't match</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br>Try again?</a></p></h2></div>";
            }

            if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE `login` SET `email`='$email' WHERE `username`='$username'");
                if (!$querychange) {
                    die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Your email has been changed</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
            }

        } else {

            echo"
            <form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
            <label>Current Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword' required><p>
            <label>New Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
            <label>Repeat New Password:*</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
            </form>
            ";

        }

} else {
    echo "You must be logged in to change your password";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in D:\xampp\htdocs\wd6\pages\changepassword.php on line 55

Comment: Fixed. Missed a parenthesis. But I also changed so the HTML is above the PHP, should work better since you are outputting the username info.